# Simple python input while loop for counting down to the weekday with str input

Tags: python, while-loop, countdown

I have this simple code

```
count_down = int(input("How many left left until the weekend?: "))
while count_down:
    print(count_down)
    count_down -= 1
print("It's the weekend!")
```

The output is a countdown:
example:

```
5
4
3
2
1
It's the weekend!
```

I'm pretty new to python. Is there a way that I can make it so that the user can input a day of the week and make it start from that day. An example would be if the persons puts down tuesday it would count down

```
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
It's the weekend!
```

Comment: Do you need this done using a while loop? or are you open to other approaches as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like for the user to input a day of the week and then countdown from that day until you reach the weekend, you can do so with the following code:

```
weekends = ['Saturday','Sunday']
weekdays = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','It\'s the weekend!']

currentDay = input('What day is it?')

if currentDay in weekdays:
    print(currentDay)
    newLst = weekdays[weekdays.index(currentDay)+1:]
    while len(newLst) > 0:
        print(newLst[0])
        newLst = newLst[1:]
elif currentDay in weekends:
    print("It\'s already the weekend!")
```

The basis of this code is essentially [slicing lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation).

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to import calendar you can make a simple list of the days of the week:

```
count_down = input("What day should we start at?: ")
week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]

for i in range(len(week)): #this will loop though the list where i is the index
   if week[i] == count_down: #then we check each index to see if it is the correct string
      count = i 
      while count < len(week): #then we count from that index
         print(week[count])
print("it is the weekend!")
```

If you are new to python and you are not interested in improving time complexity this will work.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches can be:

```
week_days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'It\'s a weekend']
curr_day = input("Current Day: ")
if (curr_day.lower() in ['saturday', 'sunday']):
    print ('You are in weekend')
else:
    start = None
    for day in week_days:
        if (curr_day.lower() == day.lower()):
            print (curr_day)
            start = True
        if curr_day.lower() != day.lower() and start:
            print (day)
            
    if (not start):
        print ('Invalid Day Given')
```

Output:

```
Current Day: Tuesday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
It's a weekend
```